# Verifying RECAPTCHA with jQuery

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I'm trying to verify a Recaptcha using jQuery, but I keep getting an error telling me: Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 var challengeVal = $("#recaptcha_challenge_field").attr("value");
 var reponseVal = $("#recaptcha_response_field").attr("value");
 var remoteIp = <%= "'" + Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] + "'" %>
 var privateKey = 'MY_PRIVATE_KEY';

 var requestUrl = "http://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify?privatekey=" + privateKey + "&remoteip=" + remoteIp + "&challenge=" + challengeVal + "&response=" + reponseVal;

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: requestUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       alert('response from recaptcha');
    },
    error: function() {
       alert("An error occured.");
    }
  });
```

Anyone tried this, who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JavaScript is prohibited from making cross-domain XMLHttpRequests for security reasons. There are [workarounds](http://ajaxian.com/archives/csshttprequest-cross-domain-ajax-using-css-for-transport), but they only work if you control both domains.

Solution: Make an AJAX-call to your own server, and contact recaptcha through server side code.

Answer (score 3):

i would look -> [racaptcha docs AJAX](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX)
there is a full example in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A full demo can be found and downloaded from [this page](http://www.darksideofthecarton.com/2008/12/15/validating-recaptcha-jquery-ajax/). But you still need to generate the public and private keys for your domain here https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Answer (score 0):

@Magnar already answered w/ respect to the security reasons. @Guido Lemmens 2 gave a PHP example. I wanted to add some ASP.NET WebForms (vs. MVC) code from another Stack [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082650/javascript-jquery-or-ajax-version-of-recaptcha-validate/10001258#10001258).